# iOS - location dynamic NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in prompt message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization, core-location

How can I change `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` string programmatically?

I don't want to rely on localized Info.plist because my application language settings are very specific.

Thanks in advance.

Michał

Comment: You can't.  The best you can do is display another alert before you request location permissions that explains why you need location access.

Comment: I think the all native need permision kind of alert shown by apple are localised!!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is **not possible** to programmatically modify value of `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thank you, so how can I change my applicaion's preferred language to use specific InfoPlist.string. I tried setting `AppleLanguages` object in `NSUserDefaults` but it doesn't work for Info.plist, only for simple localizable strings.